# spring - difference between request.setAttribute and model.addAttribute?

Tags: spring

can any one tell me the difference between `request.setAttribute` and `model.addAttribute` in spring web app?

Answer (score 11):

The difference is, that `Model` is an abstraction. You could use Spring with servlets, portlets or other frontend technologies and Model attributes will always be available in your respective views.

`HttpServletRequest` on the other hand is an object specific for Servlets. Spring will also make request attributes available in your views, just like model attributes, so from a user perspective there is not much difference.

Another aspect is that models are more lightweight and more convenient to work with (e.g iterating over all attributes in a model map is easier than in a request).

Comment: usually, dose not the attribute that had was added to model is used to using request.getAttribute('attrName') or EL? then, is there difference between request.setAttribute and model.addAttribute when iterating over all attributes

Answer (score -1):

Request V/s Model

where request could get attributes through getAttribute("") method. normally it is used for getting information from defined attributes and used inside the method for performing the different operations. So Basically Request used for input.

Just like Request, the model provides addAttribute("","") method, Through this model, we could make the object and storing data inside model object and deploying it on result Server Page.Basically it used in storing input data which is provide by us and storing for some time.