# Thymeleaf Model vs HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, web, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring and Thymeleaf. I have discovered that if I want to pass a variable between the **Controller** class and the template, I can do this in 2 ways. Either by adding it to the **org.springframework.ui.Model** object (in the **Controller** class):

```
@RequestMapping("trial")
public String trial(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("variable", "abc");
  return "trialTemplate"
}
```

or by setting the relevant attribute in the **javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest** object (in the **Controller** class):

```
@RequestMapping("trial")
public String trial(HttpServletRequest request) {
  request.setAttribute("variable", "abc");
  return "trialTemplate"
}
```

In both cases, the variable can be accessed in the template like this:

```
<td th:text="${variable}"/>
```

My question is simply what is the difference and when should you use one over the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring - difference between request.setAttribute and model.addAttribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497744/spring-difference-between-request-setattribute-and-model-addattribute)

Comment: Great! Just what I wanted. Thanks!